# Unable to query a Spark RDD using the HiveThriftServer2.startWithContext functionality

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to query a Spark RDD using the `HiveThriftServer2.startWithContext` functionality and getting the following Exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.invoke(HiveSessionProxy.java:84)
  at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.access$000(HiveSessionProxy.java:37)
  at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy$1.run(HiveSessionProxy.java:64)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure.doAs(HadoopShimsSecure.java:502)
  at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.invoke(HiveSessionProxy.java:60)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.executeStatementAsync(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.executeStatementAsync(CLIService.java:237)
  at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.ExecuteStatement(ThriftCLIService.java:392)
  at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1373)
  at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1358)
  at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
  at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
  at org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor.process(TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:55)
  at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:244)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.getIntVar(HiveConf.java:1259)
  at org.apache.hive.service.cli.log.LogManager.createNewOperationLog(LogManager.java:101)
  at org.apache.hive.service.cli.log.LogManager.getOperationLogByOperation(LogManager.java:156)
  at org.apache.hive.service.cli.log.LogManager.registerCurrentThread(LogManager.java:120)
  at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.runOperationWithLogCapture(HiveSessionImpl.java:714)
  at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementInternal(HiveSessionImpl.java:370)
  at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementAsync(HiveSessionImpl.java:357)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.invoke(HiveSessionProxy.java:79)
  ... 19 more
```

Code:

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive._

object Test1
{

  def main(args: Array[String])
  {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test1")
    val sc =  new SparkContext(sparkConf)

    ...
    val hoursAug = sqlContext.sql("SELECT H.Col1, H.Col2, U.Col3, U.Col4 " +
                                  "FROM HOURS H  " +
                                  "JOIN USERS U  " + 
                                  "ON H.User = U.USERNAME")
    hoursAug.registerTempTable("HOURS_AUGM")

    import  org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver._
    HiveThriftServer2.startWithContext(sqlContext)
  }
}
```

Environment:

- CDH 5.3
- Spark 1.3.0 (upgraded from the default Spark 1.2.0 on CDH 5.3)
- Hive Metastore is in MySQL

Configuration steps:

1. Rebuilt Spark with Hive support using the command:
   `mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0 -Phive -Phive-thriftserver -DskipTests clean package`
2. Replaced Spark Assembly jar with the result of the build.
3. Placed hive-site.xml into Spark conf directory.
4. Using Beeline to work with Spark Thrift Server. 
   The `connect` command passes successfully, but any `select` or `show tables` command results in the *Null Pointer Exception* with the stack trace as shown above. However, when starting Spark Thrift Server from command line using /usr/lib/spark/sbin/start-thriftserver.sh, I am able to see and query Hive tables.

Can you please help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Got similar when I try to load file as table content.
Please try to save RDD/DF as a permanent table, which works in my scenario -- beeline "show tables" can display the permanent table, not temporary ones

Not sure the cause yet...

Comment: Hello, you're new here; welcome :) Just a heads-up, you should only add an answer, when you have an answer. Until then you should assist the OP by commenting on his question :)